# How to Make Different Size in imageview in Tableview?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

In my project i used one `UItableview` .That `UItableview` have one `UIimageview`.I declared values in `array`.My question is  **first two rows have (23 width,23 height) IMAGEVIEW SIZE other four rows have (17width and 17 height)**  Is this possible ..Please suggest some code.

Comment: how many number of row in your one single table ?

Comment: static Row or Dynamic Row?

Comment: - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

       Here your return hight of your table row.
}

Comment: using array to create Rows...totally 6 rows

Comment: ok, use heightForRowAtIndexPath this method for it

Comment: i don't want row height..i want imageview height to different size in rows

Comment: heightForRowAtIndexPath is adjust imageview height ?

Comment: @user7306261 then use xib for this

Comment: No Story board.

Comment: then working with constrain

Comment: i am not working xib ..i am working storyboard...statically created tableview

Answer (score 0):

Write this code in cellForRow.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

if (indexPath.row < 2) { 
  cell.imgViewPhotoEffects.frame.size = CGSizeMake(width: 24, height: 24) 
} else {
  cell.imgViewPhotoEffects.frame.size = CGSizeMake(width: 17, height: 17)
}}
```

If you use auto layout, then take outlet of constraint for height and width, and change constant of them.

Answer (score -1):

it's possible simply using 2 prototype cells.In first Prototype cell create UIImagView with frame of (23 x 23) and one more UIImagView with frame of (17 x 17).Set the identifier for two prototypes.In datasource methods of tableview set identifier of prototype cells and use it based on array values.

another way is take height & width constraints outlet of imageView and change the constant based on your dynamic value.

Comment: No use of downvoting without reasons.